# Smack Api often could not disconnect from MSN. User is still appears online although i invoke disconnect method..

Tags: xmpp, smack, disconnect

I experience a quite disturbing behavior using smack to build a XMPP Client for connecting to MSN and Gtalk. I can set up the connection successfully and I can chat with my application.

But in MSN case (Not Gtalk), when I try to disconnect from MSN service. Sometimes I'm getting this exception :

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Not connected to server.
at org.jivesoftware.smack.XMPPConnection.sendPacket(XMPPConnection.java:445)
```

In catch block of this exception, I'm setting up new connection.  and then send disconnect again. In that case , I can disconnect from MSN network. But couple of seconds user is appear online again to its buddies.

Please help me with these issue. This issue is very critical for our application.

Best Regards,

Alper Ozdamar